# Pondersome or Ponderous

Tags: vocabulary

I am trying to say that someone's tone implied that they were thinking about things more thoroughly. The word ponder means to think about things more carefully so I want to use a form of that verb. "Ponderous" means slow and clumsy because of great weight. When I try to type "pondersome" it always appears with a red line underneath, so what verb form should I use?

Comment: Ponderous is a adjective; pondersome is not a word; neither are verbs. Maybe you want 'thoughtful'?

Comment: Yes something like that, thank you

Comment: @MichaelHarvey -  Whaddaya mean "verbs aren't words"?! :-)

Comment: I would just write 'Rolls eyes' but that alone does not meet the minimum number of characters.     .

Comment: _Pondering_ can be used as an adjective.

Comment: The adjective I think you're looking for is ***thought-provoking*** (makes you think / ponder). Not the same as ***thoughtful*** (reflecting an attribute of the ***writer***, or the process of writing).

Comment: *Pondersome* is not a dictionary word, but you could use it effectively as a “made up word”. It sounds like something you would find in Wodehouse, maybe as Bertie describes his thoughts on some complex matter.

Answer (score 0):

As in using this idiom:

> He was certainty **[pondering on](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ponder)** the question.

definition:

> ponder on (something) - to give great consideration to something; to
>   ruminate or think about something very deeply.

Comment: I think this is bad gramma: ""He certainly pondered the question..." or, "He pondered the question before answering." would be better.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, "ponderous" refers to an object which slow and clumsy, as due to great weight or size.  And note that it is often used in a metaphorical sense, referring to ideas and theories.

"Ponsdersome" is a rarely-used term with roughly the same meaning as "ponderous".  However, while "ponderous" tends to be applied to people or objects, "pondersome" is more often applied to ideas, and implies a more on-going awkwardness -- the process rather than the object.

> The really more **pondersome** question is whether imagery processes have
>   a special role, over verbal processes, in the construction and
>   reconstruction of mental abilities.

Quote from [Imagery in Teaching and Learning](https://books.google.com/books?id=mJPmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22pondersome%22&dq=%22pondersome%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBu5_miMXlAhVpFTQIHX2xBdIQ6AEwAXoECAIQAg)

Answer (score 0):

"His tone implied that his opinion was carefully considered..." could be one way to phrase this.

That is, he had spent a lot of time thinking about the question before answering, rather than just blurting out the first thought that came to mind.